# pdfbox: How to replace text in a PDFormXobject

Tags: java, forms, replace, pdfbox

Using the [PdfContetnStreamEditor](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/PdfContentStreamEditor.java#L36)
it's quite easy to detect and replace text.

So this should also be possible for the Form streams with a modified showForm like:

```
    @Override
    public void showForm(PDFormXObject form) throws IOException {
        formDetected = true;
        withinForm = true;
        LOGGER.warn("Form detected - will flatten page");
        // inOperator = false;
        PDStream formStream = new PDStream(document);
        replacementFormStream = formStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
        replacementForm = new ContentStreamWriter(replacementStream);
        super.showForm(form); // processing of content
        PDFormXObject newform=new PDFormXObject(formStream);
        newform.setOptionalContent(form.getOptionalContent());
        newform.setBBox(form.getBBox());
        newform.setMatrix(form.getMatrix().createAffineTransform());
        newform.setResources(form.getResources());
        withinForm = false;
    }
```

now I have a new Form and I want to replace the old one. Is there a good way to do this?

As described above the PdfContetnStreamEditor is the base and replacements in the main content are no problem.